# Best way to stop a JTree selection change from happening?

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, error-handling

I have a dialog where each entry in a JTree has its corresponding options in a different panel, which is updated when the selection changes. If options for one of the entries is set to an invalid state, when the user attempts to change to a different entry in the tree, I want there to be an error dialog and have the selection not change.

I tried doing this with a valueChangeListener on the JTree, but currently then have to have the valueChanged method call "setSelectionRow" to the old selection if there is an error. So that I don't get a StackOverflow, I set a boolean "isError" to true before I do this so that I can ignore the new valueChanged event. Somehow I have the gut feeling this is not the best solution. ;-)

How would I go about it instead? Is there a good design pattern for situations like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure it's best practice, but maybe you could put a FocusListener on the component(s) you want to validate... call your validation when the event is called and then consume then event if you don't want the focus to be moved because the validation fails?

Later Edit:

At least with java 8 (I didn't check earlier versions) this solution won't work, because the FocusEvent appears not to be a low-level event. Hence it cannot be consumed. See Method AWTEvent.consume()

Comment: This is the ideal approach, IMO

Answer (score 7):

I did not find a better way, but this approach works fine for me.
I know in Delphi it was a very convenient event: "before changing selection" where you could very easily stop changing selection.

here is my java code with prevention of infinite recursion problem

```
    navTree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {

        boolean treeSelectionListenerEnabled = true;

        public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
            if (treeSelectionListenerEnabled) {
                if (ok to change selection...) {
                    ...
                } else {
                    TreePath treePath = e.getOldLeadSelectionPath();
                    treeSelectionListenerEnabled = false;
                    try {
                        // prevent from leaving the last visited node
                        navTree.setSelectionPath(treePath);
                    } finally {
                        treeSelectionListenerEnabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

always remember to remove all listeners you added, to prevent memory leaks.

here is another approach:

```
private class VetoableTreeSelectionModel extends DefaultTreeSelectionModel {
    public void setSelectionPath(TreePath path){
        if (allow selection change?) {
            super.setSelectionPath(path);
        }
    }
}
{
    navTree.setSelectionModel(new VetoableTreeSelectionModel());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution.

In a JTree subclass:

```
protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {
        TreePath selPath = getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
        try {
            fireVetoableChange(LEAD_SELECTION_PATH_PROPERTY, getLeadSelectionPath(), selPath);
        }
        catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
            // OK, we do not want change to happen
            return;
        }

        super.processMouseEvent(e);
}
```

Then in the tree using class:

```
VetoableChangeListener vcl = new VetoableChangeListener() {

        public void vetoableChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) throws PropertyVetoException {
            if ( evt.getPropertyName().equals(JTree.LEAD_SELECTION_PATH_PROPERTY) ) {
                try {
                    <some code logic that has to be satisfied>
                } catch (InvalidInputException e) {
                    throw new PropertyVetoException("", evt);
                }

            }
        }
    };
    tree.addVetoableChangeListener(vcl);
```

The mechanism starts at the earliest possible place. Mouse action intercepted, the path to-be-selected is advertised to VetoableChangeListeners. In the concrete VCL the changing property is examined and if it is the lead selection, veto logic is checked. If vetoing is needed, the VCL throws PropertyVetoException, otherwise mouse event handling goes as usual and selection happens.
In short, this makes lead selection property become a *constrained* property.

Answer (score 0):

Set a TreeSelectionModel which implements the appropriate semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of implementing a TreeSelectionModel that wraps another TreeSelectionModel but allows selection to be vetoed:

```
public class VetoableTreeSelectionModel implements TreeSelectionModel
{
   private final ListenerList<VetoableTreeSelectionListener> m_vetoableTreeSelectionListeners = new ListenerList<VetoableTreeSelectionListener>();

   private final DefaultTreeSelectionModel m_treeSelectionModel = new DefaultTreeSelectionModel();

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public void addTreeSelectionListener(final TreeSelectionListener listener)
   {
      m_treeSelectionModel.addTreeSelectionListener(listener);
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public void removeTreeSelectionListener(final TreeSelectionListener listener)
   {
      m_treeSelectionModel.removeTreeSelectionListener(listener);
   }

   /**
    * Add a vetoable tree selection listener
    *
    * @param listener the listener
    */
   public void addVetoableTreeSelectionListener(final VetoableTreeSelectionListener listener)
   {
      m_vetoableTreeSelectionListeners.addListener(listener);
   }

   /**
    * Remove a vetoable tree selection listener
    *
    * @param listener the listener
    */
   public void removeVetoableTreeSelectionListener(final VetoableTreeSelectionListener listener)
   {
      m_vetoableTreeSelectionListeners.removeListener(listener);
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public void addPropertyChangeListener(final PropertyChangeListener listener)
   {
      m_treeSelectionModel.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public void removePropertyChangeListener(final PropertyChangeListener listener)
   {
      m_treeSelectionModel.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public void addSelectionPath(final TreePath path)
   {
      try
      {
         m_vetoableTreeSelectionListeners.fireVetoableEvent(new VetoableAction<VetoableTreeSelectionListener>() {
            public void fireEvent(final VetoableTreeSelectionListener listener) throws EventVetoedException
            {
               listener.aboutToAddSelectionPath(path);
            }});

         m_treeSelectionModel.addSelectionPath(path);
      }
      catch (final EventVetoedException e)
      {
         return;
      }
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public void addSelectionPaths(final TreePath[] paths)
   {
      try
      {
         m_vetoableTreeSelectionListeners.fireVetoableEvent(new VetoableAction<VetoableTreeSelectionListener>() {
            public void fireEvent(final VetoableTreeSelectionListener listener) throws EventVetoedException
            {
               listener.aboutToAddSelectionPaths(paths);
            }});

         m_treeSelectionModel.addSelectionPaths(paths);
      }
      catch (final EventVetoedException e)
      {
         return;
      }
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public void clearSelection()
   {
      try
      {
         m_vetoableTreeSelectionListeners.fireVetoableEvent(new VetoableAction<VetoableTreeSelectionListener>() {
            public void fireEvent(final VetoableTreeSelectionListener listener) throws EventVetoedException
            {
               listener.aboutToClearSelection();
            }});

         m_treeSelectionModel.clearSelection();
      }
      catch (final EventVetoedException e)
      {
         return;
      }
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public TreePath getLeadSelectionPath()
   {
      return m_treeSelectionModel.getLeadSelectionPath();
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public int getLeadSelectionRow()
   {
      return m_treeSelectionModel.getLeadSelectionRow();
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public int getMaxSelectionRow()
   {
      return m_treeSelectionModel.getMaxSelectionRow();
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public int getMinSelectionRow()
   {
      return m_treeSelectionModel.getMinSelectionRow();
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public RowMapper getRowMapper()
   {
      return m_treeSelectionModel.getRowMapper();
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public int getSelectionCount()
   {
      return m_treeSelectionModel.getSelectionCount();
   }

   public int getSelectionMode()
   {
      return m_treeSelectionModel.getSelectionMode();
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public TreePath getSelectionPath()
   {
      return m_treeSelectionModel.getSelectionPath();
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public TreePath[] getSelectionPaths()
   {
      return m_treeSelectionModel.getSelectionPaths();
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public int[] getSelectionRows()
   {
      return m_treeSelectionModel.getSelectionRows();
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public boolean isPathSelected(final TreePath path)
   {
      return m_treeSelectionModel.isPathSelected(path);
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public boolean isRowSelected(final int row)
   {
      return m_treeSelectionModel.isRowSelected(row);
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public boolean isSelectionEmpty()
   {
      return m_treeSelectionModel.isSelectionEmpty();
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public void removeSelectionPath(final TreePath path)
   {
      try
      {
         m_vetoableTreeSelectionListeners.fireVetoableEvent(new VetoableAction<VetoableTreeSelectionListener>() {
            public void fireEvent(final VetoableTreeSelectionListener listener) throws EventVetoedException
            {
               listener.aboutRemoveSelectionPath(path);
            }});

         m_treeSelectionModel.removeSelectionPath(path);
      }
      catch (final EventVetoedException e)
      {
         return;
      }
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public void removeSelectionPaths(final TreePath[] paths)
   {
      try
      {
         m_vetoableTreeSelectionListeners.fireVetoableEvent(new VetoableAction<VetoableTreeSelectionListener>() {
            public void fireEvent(final VetoableTreeSelectionListener listener) throws EventVetoedException
            {
               listener.aboutRemoveSelectionPaths(paths);
            }});

         m_treeSelectionModel.removeSelectionPaths(paths);
      }
      catch (final EventVetoedException e)
      {
         return;
      }
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public void resetRowSelection()
   {
      try
      {
         m_vetoableTreeSelectionListeners.fireVetoableEvent(new VetoableAction<VetoableTreeSelectionListener>() {
            public void fireEvent(final VetoableTreeSelectionListener listener) throws EventVetoedException
            {
               listener.aboutToResetRowSelection();
            }});

         m_treeSelectionModel.resetRowSelection();
      }
      catch (final EventVetoedException e)
      {
         return;
      }
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public void setRowMapper(final RowMapper newMapper)
   {
      m_treeSelectionModel.setRowMapper(newMapper);
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public void setSelectionMode(final int mode)
   {
      try
      {
         m_vetoableTreeSelectionListeners.fireVetoableEvent(new VetoableAction<VetoableTreeSelectionListener>() {
            public void fireEvent(final VetoableTreeSelectionListener listener) throws EventVetoedException
            {
               listener.aboutToSetSelectionMode(mode);
            }});

         m_treeSelectionModel.setSelectionMode(mode);
      }
      catch (final EventVetoedException e)
      {
         return;
      }
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public void setSelectionPath(final TreePath path)
   {
      try
      {
         m_vetoableTreeSelectionListeners.fireVetoableEvent(new VetoableAction<VetoableTreeSelectionListener>() {
            public void fireEvent(final VetoableTreeSelectionListener listener) throws EventVetoedException
            {
               listener.aboutToSetSelectionPath(path);
            }});

         m_treeSelectionModel.setSelectionPath(path);
      }
      catch (final EventVetoedException e)
      {
         return;
      }
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public void setSelectionPaths(final TreePath[] paths)
   {
      try
      {
         m_vetoableTreeSelectionListeners.fireVetoableEvent(new VetoableAction<VetoableTreeSelectionListener>() {
            public void fireEvent(final VetoableTreeSelectionListener listener) throws EventVetoedException
            {
               listener.aboutToSetSelectionPaths(paths);
            }});

         m_treeSelectionModel.setSelectionPaths(paths);
      }
      catch (final EventVetoedException e)
      {
         return;
      }
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
      return m_treeSelectionModel.toString();
   }
```

}

And here is the listener to go with it:

```
public interface VetoableTreeSelectionListener
{
   /**
    * About to add a path to the selection
    *
    * @param path the path to add
    *
    * @throws EventVetoedException
    */
   void aboutToAddSelectionPath(TreePath path) throws EventVetoedException;

   /**
    * About to add paths to the selection
    *
    * @param paths the paths to add
    *
    * @throws EventVetoedException
    */
   void aboutToAddSelectionPaths(TreePath[] paths) throws EventVetoedException;

   /**
    * About to clear selection
    *
    * @throws EventVetoedException
    */
   void aboutToClearSelection() throws EventVetoedException;

   /**
    * About to remove a selection path
    *
    * @param path the path
    *
    * @throws EventVetoedException
    */
   void aboutRemoveSelectionPath(TreePath path) throws EventVetoedException;

   /**
    * About to remove multiple selection paths
    *
    * @param paths the paths
    *
    * @throws EventVetoedException
    */
   void aboutRemoveSelectionPaths(TreePath[] paths) throws EventVetoedException;

   /**
    * About to reset the row selection
    *
    * @throws EventVetoedException
    */
   void aboutToResetRowSelection() throws EventVetoedException;

   /**
    * About to set the selection mode
    *
    * @param mode the selection mode
    *
    * @throws EventVetoedException
    */
   void aboutToSetSelectionMode(int mode) throws EventVetoedException;

   /**
    * About to set the selection path
    *
    * @param path the path
    *
    * @throws EventVetoedException
    */
   void aboutToSetSelectionPath(TreePath path) throws EventVetoedException;

   /**
    * About to set the selection paths
    *
    * @param paths the paths
    *
    * @throws EventVetoedException
    */
   void aboutToSetSelectionPaths(TreePath[] paths) throws EventVetoedException;
}
```

You can use your own implementation of ListenerList, but you get the idea...

Answer (score 0):

To prevent selection I just subclassed DefaultTreeSelectionModel and overrode all the methods to check for objects that I didn't want to be selected (instances of "DisplayRepoOwner" in my example below). If the object was OK to be selected, I called the super method; otherwise I didn't. I set my JTree's selection model to an instance of that subclass.

```
public class MainTreeSelectionModel extends DefaultTreeSelectionModel {
public void addSelectionPath(TreePath path) {
    if (path.getLastPathComponent() instanceof DisplayRepoOwner) {
        return;
    }
    super.addSelectionPath(path);
}
public void addSelectionPaths(TreePath[] paths) {
    for (TreePath tp : paths) {
        if (tp.getLastPathComponent() instanceof DisplayRepoOwner) {
            return;
        }
    }
    super.addSelectionPaths(paths);
}
public void setSelectionPath(TreePath path) {
    if (path.getLastPathComponent() instanceof DisplayRepoOwner) {
        return;
    }
    super.setSelectionPath(path);
}
public void setSelectionPaths(TreePath[] paths) {
    for (TreePath tp : paths) {
        if (tp.getLastPathComponent() instanceof DisplayRepoOwner) {
            return;
        }
    }
    super.setSelectionPaths(paths);
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Stumbled across this thread while investigating a solution for the same problem. First, let me tell you things that didn't work. I attempted to register MouseListeners and all of that with the tree. The problem was that the TreeUI's mouse listeners were getting to the process the event before my JTree did, meaning it was too late to set a flag or anything like that. Besides that this solution produced some ugly code and I would generally avoid it.

So now for the actual solution!
After using a few Thread.dumpStack() calls to get a stack dump, I found the method I was looking to override. I extended the BasicTreeUI and overrode the "protected void selectPathForEvent(TreePath path, MouseEvent event)".

This will give you access to the mouse event that caused the selection before the selection actually occurs. You can then use whatever logic you need to either event.consume() and return if you want to stop the selection, do whatever selection you want or pass it up for default processing by calling super.selectPathForEvent(path, event);

Just remember to set the UI you created in JTree. That mistake wasted a few minuets of my life ;-)