# JTree cell editor receives mouse clicks differently depending on OS

Tags: java, macos, swing, listener, jtree

I've created a tree cell renderer/editor framework that is admittedly a little bit hacky, but it works perfectly on Windows and Linux.  The image below illustrates a sample setup.

[image]

The goal is that if the user clicks on the **image** (numeral) 1 or 2, then the application responds to that click but does not select the tree row.  If the user clicks on the **text** one or two, the application responds to that click and *does* select the tree row.  The way I've implemented this, again, is a little hacky.  Basically when the user clicks on the tree row, the editor component is displayed (which looks identical to the renderer component), and the editor component has a mouse listener which can determine where the user clicked in the row.

The fact that this works on Windows/Linux relies on something which I always thought seemed flimsy to rely on.  Basically, if you click the row a single time, that single click both (a) brings up the editor and (b) activates the mouse listener on the editor component.  This is the way I want it!  However, when you try running the app on Mac OSX (10.6.2 if it matters), the aforementioned flimsy assumption no longer holds true.  Any time you want to interact with the tree, you have to click twice (once to activate the editor, and again to activate the mouse listener).

The SSCCE below can reproduce the behavior.  Of course, if you don't have OSX you can't reproduce the **undesired** behavior, but perhaps you can still recommend a smarter way to accomplish my goal.  Watch the console for `sysout` messages indicated what's happening as you click the various parts of the tree.

Oh, and the SSCCE references these two images:

[image: image 1]  [image: iamge 2]

```
package TreeTest;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.EventObject;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellEditor;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TreeTest extends JComponent {

    private JFrame frame;
    private DefaultTreeModel treeModel;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode root;
    private JTree tree;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TreeTest window = new TreeTest();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                    window.frame.requestFocusInWindow();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public TreeTest() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame("Tree Test");
        frame.setBounds(400, 400, 250, 150);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("root");
        treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
        tree = new JTree(treeModel);
        tree.setEditable(true);
        tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(
            TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
        tree.setRootVisible(false);
        tree.setShowsRootHandles(false);
        tree.setCellRenderer(new TreeRenderer());
        tree.setCellEditor(new TreeEditor());
        tree.putClientProperty("JTree.lineStyle", "None");
        tree.setBackground(Color.white);

        treeModel.insertNodeInto(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("two"), root, 0);
        treeModel.insertNodeInto(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("one"), root, 0);

        TreeNode[] nodes = treeModel.getPathToRoot(root);
        tree.expandPath(new TreePath(nodes));
        tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("SELECTION CHANGED!");
            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(tree);
    }

    public class TreeComponent extends JPanel {

        public TreeComponent(JLabel numIcon, JLabel numText) {
            this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
            this.add(numIcon);
            this.add(numText);
        }
    }

    public class TreeRenderer implements TreeCellRenderer {

        private ImageIcon oneIcon;
        private ImageIcon twoIcon;

        public TreeRenderer() {
            try {
                oneIcon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(
                    new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dp6a.png")));
                twoIcon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(
                    new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/UteiP.png")));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
            boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
            boolean hasFocus) {
            JLabel numIcon = new JLabel();
            numIcon.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            numIcon.setAlignmentY(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            numIcon.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 4));

            JLabel numText = new JLabel();

            TreeComponent comp = new TreeComponent(numIcon, numText);

            String str = (String) ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();
            if (str.equals("one")) {
                numIcon.setIcon(oneIcon);
                numText.setText("one");
            } else if (str.equals("two")) {
                numIcon.setIcon(twoIcon);
                numText.setText("two");
            }

            numText.setOpaque(true);
            if (selected) {
                numText.setBackground(new Color(209, 230, 255));
                numText.setBorder(new LineBorder(
                    new Color(132, 172, 221), 1, false));
            } else {
                numText.setBackground(Color.white);
                numText.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.white, 1, false));
            }
            comp.setFocusable(false);
            comp.setBackground(Color.white);
            return comp;
        }
    }

    public class TreeEditor implements TreeCellEditor {

        private TreeRenderer rend;
        private TreeComponent editorComponent;
        private JTree tree;
        private DefaultTreeModel treeModel;
        private DefaultMutableTreeNode node;
        private String str;

        public TreeEditor() {
            rend = new TreeRenderer();
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(
            final JTree tree, final Object value, boolean isSelected,
            boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row) {
            this.tree = tree;
            treeModel = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
            node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
            Object userObject = node.getUserObject();
            this.str = (String) userObject;

            TreeNode[] nodes = treeModel.getPathToRoot(node);
            final TreePath path = new TreePath(nodes);

            editorComponent = (TreeComponent) rend.getTreeCellRendererComponent(
                tree, value, isSelected, expanded, leaf, row, false);
            editorComponent.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    TreeEditor.this.stopCellEditing();
                    int x = e.getX();
                    if (x >= 0 && x <= 16) {
                        System.out.println(
                            "you clicked the image for row " + str);
                    } else if (x > 16) {
                        System.out.println(
                            "you clicked the text for row " + str);
                        tree.setSelectionPath(path);
                    }
                }
            });
            return editorComponent;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean stopCellEditing() {
            tree.cancelEditing();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelCellEditing() {
        }

        @Override
        public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
        }

        @Override
        public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unrelated or not, didn't dig: your editor implementation is invalid! It _must not_ act on the tree directly, it _must_ notify its listeners when ready. Minor asides: don't create new components in getXXComponent, don't add listeners more than once (that mouseListener looks fishy anyway, as it interacts with the tree which it shouldn't)

Comment: okay, just read your comments to @trashgod's answer - it's not meant to be an editor :-) And I see the problem: the area between a renderer and an editor is slippy ground, somthing like not-an-editor-but-mouse-active is not supported and difficult to fake. My personal preference in such a case is to not mis-use the editor, but add control logic on the tree itself ... will check what we have in the swingx incubator (will be half baked, though)

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks, I am trying to review some other options.  Why do you say not to create new components in getXXComponent?

Comment: @kleopatra I've come up with a new approach which is still probably a bit of a hack, but doesn't use an editor at all.  I would welcome your comments as a known Swing guru. :-)  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15752792/912935) please.  Thanks.

Comment: actually, I don't understand your need for _not_ using a plain editor: all the data that's represented by the different components in the rendering/editing component are properties of your node's userObject - implement the editor correctly and let it do its job, then all will nicely fall into place, without any tricks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick outline of how to implement complex cellEditors. The assumption is that all interactive elements of the editor do indeed edit a property of the node's userObject - as is the case in the OP's full code.

The collaborators

- a mock Data object with several properties
- a renderer with several children, each bound to one property of the data object
- an editor which uses an "live" instance of the rendering component, that is adds listeners to comply to editor's contract as needed

Some code (obviously *not* usable for real-world usage, just to get the idea :)

```
public static class ViewProvider extends AbstractCellEditor 
    implements TreeCellEditor, TreeCellRenderer {

    private JCheckBox firstBox;
    private JButton colorButton;
    private JComponent nodePanel;
    private JButton nameButton;

    private Data data;
    private boolean ignore;

    public ViewProvider(boolean asEditor) {
        initComponents();
        if (asEditor)
          installListeners();
    }

    protected void initComponents() {
        nodePanel = new JPanel();
        nodePanel.setOpaque(false);
        firstBox = new JCheckBox();
        colorButton = new JButton();
        // if we need something clickable use something ... clickable :-)
        nameButton = new JButton();
        nameButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        nameButton.setOpaque(true);
        nameButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        nameButton.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        nodePanel.add(firstBox);
        nodePanel.add(colorButton);
        nodePanel.add(nameButton);
    }

    protected void installListeners() {
        ActionListener cancel = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cancelCellEditing();
            }

        };
        nameButton.addActionListener(cancel);
        ActionListener stop = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                stopCellEditing();
            }

        };
        firstBox.addActionListener(stop);
        // Note: code for using a button to trigger opening a dialog
        // is in the tutorial, should replace this
        colorButton.addActionListener(stop);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
            boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
            boolean hasFocus) {
        Data data = (Data) ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();
        firstBox.setSelected(data.isVisible);
        colorButton.setBackground(data.color);
        nameButton.setText(data.name);
        nameButton.setBackground(selected ? Color.YELLOW : tree.getBackground());
        nameButton.setFont(tree.getFont());
        return nodePanel;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row) {
        // copy to not fiddle with the original
        data = new Data((Data) ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject());
        ignore = true;
        getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, isSelected, expanded, leaf, row, false);
        ignore = false;
        return nodePanel;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
        // at this point the editing component is added to the tree
        // and the mouse coordinates still in tree coordinates
        if (anEvent instanceof MouseEvent) {
            MouseEvent me = (MouseEvent) anEvent;
            Point loc = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(me.getComponent(), 
                    me.getPoint(), nodePanel);
            return loc.x >= nameButton.getX();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        if (ignore) return false;
        // real-world data will have setters
        data.isVisible = firstBox.isSelected();
        return super.stopCellEditing();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelCellEditing() {
        if (ignore) return;
        data = null;
        super.cancelCellEditing();
    }

}

// simple Data - obviously not for production 
public static class Data {
    boolean isVisible;
    Color color;
    String name;

    public Data(boolean isVisible, Color color,
            String name) {
        this.isVisible = isVisible;
        this.color = color;
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * A copy constructor to allow editors to manipulate its
     * properties without changing the original.
     * 
     * @param original
     */
    public Data(Data original) {
        this.isVisible = original.isVisible;
        this.color = original.color;
        this.name = original.name;
    }
}

// usage:
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(
    new Data(true, Color.RED, "someName"));
root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new Data(true, Color.GREEN, "other")));
root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new Data(false, Color.BLUE, "whatagain")));
root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new Data(false, Color.YELLOW, "dummy")));

JTree tree = new JTree(root);
tree.setCellRenderer(new ViewProvider(false));
tree.setCellEditor(new ViewProvider(true));
tree.setEditable(true);
```

Comment: @mKorbel did I? Can't remember and doesn't make much sense to me, now :-)

Comment: +1, it does seem to work, though I echo @mKorbel's amusement that you now support the use of an editor for this behavior. :-)  More importantly though, I can't figure out why your code here works on OSX, but mine in the OP didn't.  I can't seem to nail down what you're doing differently that lets the same click be used to both (a) bring the editor up and (b) USE the editor.  Any ideas?

Comment: @The111 Each button corresponds to either a boolean flag or the color of the GPSObject and changes it, which is called ... editing :-) Nothing special, just playing by the rules for editors: the initial trigger is (as in: should be, there had been bugs in earlier versions) passed into the editor once it is added.

Comment: actually, I don't quite follow the amusement @mKorbel, biased me would suspect a misunderstanding - _usage_ of a JPanel in a renderer/editor is no problem, while _extension_ of any JSomething with a new role a renderer/editor is :-) So if anybody has a link to me preaching against the former, please let know, should be deleted <g>

Comment: 1. JButton(s) with whatever in side (Icon, text, alinment, implemented Listeners) is(are) best of, most.... , 2. great as you are, 3. my FlameWar deleted, saved to bad times :-) 4. notice still isn't possible to serch in own comments, question was twice closed, then I deleted them 5. thank you for clear ideas in code after last edit

Comment: Sorry, my "amusement" was based on the fact that I _thought_ both you and trashgod earlier told me this problem was not the right place to use an editor at all.  But, I guess that was because my SSCCE did not properly illustrate my actual usage.  So, probably my bad.  But I'm still confused since **your** editor returns a JComp with listeners, which pick up the first mouse click, and **my** editor was also returning a JComp with listeners, which would not pick up the first mouse click (on OSX only).  I wonder if it's because you used listeners on a button, not a panel.  I have to test more.

Comment: @The111 no problem :-) Again: your editor implementation was _invalid_ - which can have whatever unpredictable (read: unexpected) results

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand the requirement, but the example below adds a convenient key binding and works with either *single-click* approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15625424/230513). I've chosen to override `canEditImmediately()`, as suggested by [kleopatra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15637927/230513), subject to her caveats concerning usability.

[image: tree image]

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.EventObject;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellEditor;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15738813/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/15625424/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private static Icon one;
    private static Icon two;

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JTree tree = new JTree();
        for (int i = 0; i < tree.getRowCount(); i++) {
            tree.expandRow(i);
        }
        final TreeRenderer renderer = new TreeRenderer();
        tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);
        tree.setCellEditor(new TreeEditor(tree, renderer));
        tree.setEditable(true);
        tree.getInputMap().put(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "startEditing");
        f.add(new JScrollPane(tree));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class TreeRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
            boolean sel, boolean exp, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
            String s = node.getUserObject().toString();
            if ("colors".equals(s)) {
                setOpenIcon(one);
                setClosedIcon(one);
            } else if ("sports".equals(s)) {
                setOpenIcon(two);
                setClosedIcon(two);
            } else {
                setOpenIcon(getDefaultOpenIcon());
                setClosedIcon(getDefaultClosedIcon());
            }
            super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(
                tree, value, sel, exp, leaf, row, hasFocus);
            return this;
        }
    }

    private static class TreeEditor extends DefaultTreeCellEditor {

        public TreeEditor(JTree tree, DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer) {
            super(tree, renderer);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean exp, boolean leaf, int row) {
            Component c = super.getTreeCellEditorComponent(
                tree, value, isSelected, exp, leaf, row);
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
            String s = node.getUserObject().toString();
            if ("colors".equals(s)) {
                editingIcon = one;
            } else if ("sports".equals(s)) {
                editingIcon = two;
            }
            return c;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean canEditImmediately(EventObject event) {
            if ((event instanceof MouseEvent)
                && SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton((MouseEvent) event)) {
                MouseEvent me = (MouseEvent) event;

                return ((me.getClickCount() >= 1)
                    && inHitRegion(me.getX(), me.getY()));
            }
            return (event == null);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        one = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(
            new URL("http://i.imgur.com/HtHJkfI.png")));
        two = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(
            new URL("http://i.imgur.com/w5jAp5c.png")));
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks as always for the input, trashgod.  However, I don't think the answer I'm looking for is in there.  Perhaps I should explain my requirements better, as I can understand your confusion.  Check my actual application [here](http://www.gpxcreator.com/).  Hit CTRL+N to make a new file and then play with the tree on the left.  In my app, the user never actually _edits_ the tree, he merely uses it for interaction.  Each icon in a tree row does something different, and the row should not get _selected_ unless the user clicks on the text.

Comment: I'm using an editor, which is admittedly kind of illogical (since no editing is actually going on), because I can't figure any other way to accomplish my goal!  If the tree renderer gave me an option to render real components then I could attach my click listeners to them.  But it doesn't, so I'm attaching them to the editor, which both comes up AND gets clicked on with the same click, and then makes itself go away, all transparent to the user.  But on OSX, this takes two clicks every time.  I believe you're on a Mac, so perhaps you can offer even better insight.  Hope that elaboration helps!

Comment: Sorry, you're trying to defeat the UI delegate with an unnecessary  editor—a doomed approach. Why not look at [`Outline`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692), which makes adding row components easy. It works with any `TreeModel`.

Comment: Agreed, the editor was never needed.  I've come up with a new approach which is still probably a bit of a hack, but doesn't use an editor at all.  I would welcome your comments.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15752792/912935) please.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with something that creates my desired behavior and does not use a `TreeCellEditor` at all.  Instead, the tree is uneditable, and is instantiated with a custom extension of `JTree` which has `processMouseEvent` overridden.  I got this idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3157215/912935).

It seems to work perfect, but it is still a little bit hacky (it does a loop of calculations to determine where the start of the tree cell is, since that can vary based on indentation).  Also I pretty much disabled `mouseClicked` and `mouseReleased` type events, and am controlling the `JTreeMod` only with `mousePressed` events.  Not sure if this will bite me later or is bad practice, but I didn't like my custom code running 3 times in a row for all the events.  I also haven't been able to test on a non-Windows OS just yet.

Here is the console output after clicking, in series (1) the image one (2) the text one (3) the image two (4) the text two.  Again, this perfectly implements my desired behavior.

```
you clicked the image for row 1. this was detected, but no selection will happen!
you clicked the text for row 1. this was detected, and selection WILL happen!
SELECTION CHANGED!
you clicked the image for row 2. this was detected, but no selection will happen!
you clicked the text for row 2. this was detected, and selection WILL happen!
SELECTION CHANGED!
```

And here is the new SSCCE:

```
package TreeTest;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TreeTest2 extends JComponent {

    private JFrame frame;
    private DefaultTreeModel treeModel;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode root;
    private JTreeMod tree;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TreeTest2 window = new TreeTest2();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                    window.frame.requestFocusInWindow();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public TreeTest2() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame("Tree Test");
        frame.setBounds(400, 400, 250, 150);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("root");
        treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
        tree = new JTreeMod(treeModel);
        tree.setEditable(false);
        tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(
            TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
        tree.setRootVisible(false);
        tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);
        tree.setCellRenderer(new TreeRenderer());
        tree.putClientProperty("JTree.lineStyle", "None");
        tree.setBackground(Color.white);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode one = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("one");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode two = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("two");

        treeModel.insertNodeInto(one, root, 0);
        treeModel.insertNodeInto(two, one, 0);

        TreeNode[] nodes = treeModel.getPathToRoot(root);
        tree.expandPath(new TreePath(nodes));
        nodes = treeModel.getPathToRoot(one);
        tree.expandPath(new TreePath(nodes));
        tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("SELECTION CHANGED!");
            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(tree);
    }

    public class TreeRenderer implements TreeCellRenderer {

        private ImageIcon oneIcon;
        private ImageIcon twoIcon;

        public TreeRenderer() {
            try {
                oneIcon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(
                        new URL("http://i.imgur.com/HtHJkfI.png")));
                twoIcon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(
                        new URL("http://i.imgur.com/w5jAp5c.png")));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
            boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
            boolean hasFocus) {
            JLabel numIcon = new JLabel();
            numIcon.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            numIcon.setAlignmentY(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            numIcon.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 4));

            JLabel numText = new JLabel();

            JPanel comp = new JPanel();
            comp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(comp, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
            comp.add(numIcon);
            comp.add(numText);

            String str = (String) ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();
            if (str.equals("one")) {
                numIcon.setIcon(oneIcon);
                numText.setText("one");
            } else if (str.equals("two")) {
                numIcon.setIcon(twoIcon);
                numText.setText("two");
            }

            numText.setOpaque(true);
            if (selected) {
                numText.setBackground(new Color(209, 230, 255));
                numText.setBorder(new LineBorder(
                    new Color(132, 172, 221), 1, false));
            } else {
                numText.setBackground(Color.white);
                numText.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.white, 1, false));
            }
            comp.setFocusable(false);
            comp.setBackground(Color.white);
            return comp;
        }
    }

    public class JTreeMod extends JTree {
        public JTreeMod(DefaultTreeModel treeModel) {
            super(treeModel);
        }

        @Override
        protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {
            int type = e.getID();
            if (type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED || type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED) {
                // do nothing
            } else if (type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();

                int row = this.getRowForLocation(x, y);
                if (row == -1) {
                    super.processMouseEvent(e);
                    return;
                }

                int xOffset = x;
                int row1 = row;
                while (row1 == row) {
                    xOffset--;
                    row1 = this.getRowForLocation(xOffset, y);
                }
                xOffset++;

                if (x - xOffset <= 16) {
                    System.out.println("you clicked the image for row " + (row + 1) +
                            ". this was detected, but no selection will happen!");
                    return;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("you clicked the text for row " + (row + 1) + 
                            ". this was detected, and selection WILL happen!");
                    super.processMouseEvent(e);
                }
            } else {
                super.processMouseEvent(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for an [sscce](http://sscce.org/), although I think it highlights the awkwardness of the approach. In `Outline`, these would be normal renderers (and perhaps editors) in your `RowModel`.

Comment: @trashgod thanks, I will look into `Outline` sometime soon but this solution will tide me over in the meantime.